# How to merge rows with the mean values using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, mean

This is a hypothetical question, I really haven't tried anything yet as I am not entirely sure this is even possible. I am trying to see if by merging a set of data of the same patients, will that improve the algorithm of diagnosis?

I have the following data:

| patient | data 1 | data 2 | data 3 | data 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| patient1 | data.patient1 | data.patient1 | data.patient1 | data.patient1 |
| patient1 | data.patient1 | data.patient1 | data.patient1 | data.patient1 |
| patient1 | data.patient1 | data.patient1 | data.patient1 | data.patient1 |
| patient1 | data.patient1 | data.patient1 | data.patient1 | data.patient1 |
| patient1 | data.patient1 | data.patient1 | data.patient1 | data.patient1 |
| patient2 | data.patient2 | data.patient2 | data.patient2 | data.patient2 |
| patient2 | data.patient2 | data.patient2 | data.patient2 | data.patient2 |
| patient2 | data.patient2 | data.patient2 | data.patient2 | data.patient2 |
| (...) | (...) | (...) | (...) | (...) |

As the table has the same pattern (every patient has 6 rows of data). Is there a way of summing the data every 6 rows and obtaining the mean value?

Comment: `df.groupby('patient').mean()`

Comment: Unfortunately, the patient's column is actually phon_R01_S01_1, phon_R01_S01_2, phon_R01_S01_3, phon_R01_S01_4, phon_R01_S01_5 and phon_R01_S01_6 varying the number after the letter S.

Comment: Then you can `rsplit` the string with a limit of 1, and group on only the part before the last underscore.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using pandas. 
Assuming you have the table loaded in a dataframe df,

In general, for all columns it would be

```
df['col_mean'] = df.mean(axis=1)
```

You could also use the following code for individual columns.

```
df['col_mean'] = df[['data1', 'data2']].mean(axis=1)
```

[Link to documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html)
Hope this helps!